# Error trying to join 3 csv tables together in Pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

```
housing_temp = [cal_housing, proximity]
```

This is the code I'm using ^.
Then I run this:

```
housing = pd.DataFrame(housing_temp)
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)

I'm not sure why it's not working, as it had previously. Will load my data in a comment.

Comment: dput(head(long_lat.csv)), dput(head(ocean_proximity.csv))

Comment: I don't think it's working. Grr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pd. concat

```
df=  pd.concat(housing_temp)
```